# What is a person who is discriminated against called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an essay and I was wondering what would you call a person who is discriminated against.

Comment: Legally, probably the "injured party." More commonly you hear "victim."

Comment: I would suggest - *a victim of discrimination*

Comment: I'm guessing you're aiming for more technical terms, but I'll throw in ***pariah*** or ***outcast*** as possibilities depending on the context. Indeed, if you could specify how this person is being discriminated against, it may help you get better answers. In the term's most literal sense, to discriminate only means to judge things in comparison to other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **[discriminatee](https://www.google.com/search?q=discriminate&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg-eTbos7JAhVEcHIKHQZEClUQBQgYKAA#q=discriminatee&tbm=bks)** is also used, particularly in legal documents:

> In Precoat, the Board found an alleged **discriminatee** had "forfeited his entitlement to reinstatement and backpay" because he gave false testimony...

([Decisions and Orders of the National Labor Relations Board, Volume 349](https://books.google.com/books?id=EUcvlaXSaEcC&pg=PA1131&lpg=PA1131&dq=discriminatee&source=bl&ots=80tot6F1wb&sig=SPMEbNtbTfwrwxHKbbBQHNEVrWo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj45sfjos7JAhUhdXIKHRBBDpMQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q&f=false))

> The Administrative Law Judge’s decision covers **two broad categories of discriminatees**. The first category of discriminatees are former TVS employees who **were not hired by CNN** after the contracts with TVS were cancelled in late 2003 in Washington, D.C. and early 2004 in New York, N.Y.
>
> These discriminatees are entitled to be reinstated to their former jobs or, if those jobs no longer exist, to substantially equivalent positions **without prejudice to their seniority or any other rights or privileges** that they previously enjoyed as employees of TVS.

([CNN/TVS NLRB Case Decision - FAQ](http://www.nabet31.org/cnn-nlrb-case-desc-faq))

Answer (score 5):

In general usage, **victim of discrimination** is widespread. See, for instance, [the EEOC](http://www.eeoc.gov/employees/remedies.cfm).